# Не работает код js

Tags: javascript

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Транскриптор</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
    .html, body{
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
    }
    #russian_text, #deutch_text {
     height: 15em;
     width: 30em;
     margin: 10px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
    function transcript(){
    var str = document.getElementById('deutch_text').value;
    var arr = str.split("");
    var i;
     for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
      
    
      if (arr[i] === "a") {
      arr[i] = "ф";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "A") {
      arr[i] = "Ф";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "b") {
      arr[i] = "и"; 
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "B") {
       arr[i] = "И";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "c") {
       arr[i] = "с";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "C") {
       arr[i] = "С";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "D") {
       arr[i] = "В";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "d") {
       arr[i] = "в";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "E") {
       arr[i] = "У";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "e") {
       arr[i] = "у";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "f") {
       arr[i] = "а";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "F") {
       arr[i] = "А;
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "g") {
       arr[i] = "п";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "G") {
       arr[i] = "П";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "h") {
       arr[i] = "р";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "H") {
       arr[i] = "Р";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "i") {
       arr[i] = "ш;
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "I") {
       arr[i] = "Ш";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "J") {
       arr[i] = "о";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "j") {
       arr[i] = "О";
      }
      
      else if (arr[i] === "k") {
       arr[i] = "л";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "K") {
       arr[i] = "Л";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "l") {
       arr[i] = "д";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "L") {
       arr[i] = "Д";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "m") {
       arr[i] = "ь";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "M") {
       arr[i] = "Ь";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "n") {
       arr[i] = "т";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "N") {
       arr[i] = "Т";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "o") {
       arr[i] = "щ";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "O") {
       arr[i] = "Щ";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "p") {
       arr[i] = "з";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "P") {
       arr[i] = "З";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "q") {
       arr[i] = "й";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "Q") {
       arr[i] = "Й";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "r") {
       arr[i] = "к";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "R") {
       arr[i] = "К";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "s") {
       arr[i] = "ы";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "S") {
       arr[i] = "Ы";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "t") {
       arr[i] = "е";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "T") {
       arr[i] = "Е";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "u") {
       arr[i] = "г";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "U") {
       arr[i] = "Г";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "v") {
       arr[i] = "м";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "V") {
       arr[i] = "М";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "w") {
       arr[i] = "ц";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "W") {
       arr[i] = "Ц";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "X") {
       arr[i] = "Ч";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "x") {
       arr[i] = "ч";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "y") {
       arr[i] = "н";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "Y") {
       arr[i] = "Н";
       }
      else if (arr[i] === "z") {
       arr[i] = "я";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "Z") {
       arr[i] = "Я";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "`") {
       arr[i] = "ё";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "~") {
       arr[i] = "Ё";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "@") {
       arr[i] = "\"";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "#") {
       arr[i] = "№";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "$") {
       arr[i] = ";";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "^") {
       arr[i] = ":";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "&") {
       arr[i] = "?";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "[") {
       arr[i] = "х";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "{") {
       arr[i] = "Х";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "]") {
       arr[i] = "ъ";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "}") {
       arr[i] = "Ъ";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "|") {
       arr[i] = "/";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === ";") {
       arr[i]="ж";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === ":") {
       arr[i]="Ж";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "'") {
       arr[i]="э";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "\"") {
       arr[i]="Э";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === ",") {
       arr[i]="б";
      }
      else if (arr[i] === "<") {
       arr[i]="Б";
      }
    
      else{
       arr[i]=arr[i];
      }
      
      
      }
      russian_text.value = arr.join('');
      
      
     }
    
    </script>
    <form onsubmit="transcript();">
    <input type="text" id="deutch_text" placeholder="Текст на немецком">
    <input type="text" id="russian_text" placeholder="Текст на русском" disabled>
    <input type="button" value="Транскрибировать" onclick = "transcript();">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

По идее в russian_text должен выводится результат в js, но он не выводится. Почему?

Answer (score 3):

Пропущены закрывающие кавычки в строках:

```
          arr[i] = "А;
          arr[i] = "ш;
```

---

*Совет дня:*

> Не забывайте читать сообщения об ошибках в консоли браузера.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Транскриптор</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style type="text/css">
    .html,
    body {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    #russian_text,
    #deutch_text {
      height: 15em;
      width: 30em;
      margin: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    function transcript() {
      var str = document.getElementById('deutch_text').value;
      var arr = str.split("");
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {


        if (arr[i] === "a") {
          arr[i] = "ф";
        } else if (arr[i] === "A") {
          arr[i] = "Ф";
        } else if (arr[i] === "b") {
          arr[i] = "и";
        } else if (arr[i] === "B") {
          arr[i] = "И";
        } else if (arr[i] === "c") {
          arr[i] = "с";
        } else if (arr[i] === "C") {
          arr[i] = "С";
        } else if (arr[i] === "D") {
          arr[i] = "В";
        } else if (arr[i] === "d") {
          arr[i] = "в";
        } else if (arr[i] === "E") {
          arr[i] = "У";
        } else if (arr[i] === "e") {
          arr[i] = "у";
        } else if (arr[i] === "f") {
          arr[i] = "а";
        } else if (arr[i] === "F") {
          arr[i] = "А"; // !!!
        } else if (arr[i] === "g") {
          arr[i] = "п";
        } else if (arr[i] === "G") {
          arr[i] = "П";
        } else if (arr[i] === "h") {
          arr[i] = "р";
        } else if (arr[i] === "H") {
          arr[i] = "Р";
        } else if (arr[i] === "i") {
          arr[i] = "ш"; // !!!
        } else if (arr[i] === "I") {
          arr[i] = "Ш";
        } else if (arr[i] === "J") {
          arr[i] = "о";
        } else if (arr[i] === "j") {
          arr[i] = "О";
        } else if (arr[i] === "k") {
          arr[i] = "л";
        } else if (arr[i] === "K") {
          arr[i] = "Л";
        } else if (arr[i] === "l") {
          arr[i] = "д";
        } else if (arr[i] === "L") {
          arr[i] = "Д";
        } else if (arr[i] === "m") {
          arr[i] = "ь";
        } else if (arr[i] === "M") {
          arr[i] = "Ь";
        } else if (arr[i] === "n") {
          arr[i] = "т";
        } else if (arr[i] === "N") {
          arr[i] = "Т";
        } else if (arr[i] === "o") {
          arr[i] = "щ";
        } else if (arr[i] === "O") {
          arr[i] = "Щ";
        } else if (arr[i] === "p") {
          arr[i] = "з";
        } else if (arr[i] === "P") {
          arr[i] = "З";
        } else if (arr[i] === "q") {
          arr[i] = "й";
        } else if (arr[i] === "Q") {
          arr[i] = "Й";
        } else if (arr[i] === "r") {
          arr[i] = "к";
        } else if (arr[i] === "R") {
          arr[i] = "К";
        } else if (arr[i] === "s") {
          arr[i] = "ы";
        } else if (arr[i] === "S") {
          arr[i] = "Ы";
        } else if (arr[i] === "t") {
          arr[i] = "е";
        } else if (arr[i] === "T") {
          arr[i] = "Е";
        } else if (arr[i] === "u") {
          arr[i] = "г";
        } else if (arr[i] === "U") {
          arr[i] = "Г";
        } else if (arr[i] === "v") {
          arr[i] = "м";
        } else if (arr[i] === "V") {
          arr[i] = "М";
        } else if (arr[i] === "w") {
          arr[i] = "ц";
        } else if (arr[i] === "W") {
          arr[i] = "Ц";
        } else if (arr[i] === "X") {
          arr[i] = "Ч";
        } else if (arr[i] === "x") {
          arr[i] = "ч";
        } else if (arr[i] === "y") {
          arr[i] = "н";
        } else if (arr[i] === "Y") {
          arr[i] = "Н";
        } else if (arr[i] === "z") {
          arr[i] = "я";
        } else if (arr[i] === "Z") {
          arr[i] = "Я";
        } else if (arr[i] === "`") {
          arr[i] = "ё";
        } else if (arr[i] === "~") {
          arr[i] = "Ё";
        } else if (arr[i] === "@") {
          arr[i] = "\"";
        } else if (arr[i] === "#") {
          arr[i] = "№";
        } else if (arr[i] === "$") {
          arr[i] = ";";
        } else if (arr[i] === "^") {
          arr[i] = ":";
        } else if (arr[i] === "&") {
          arr[i] = "?";
        } else if (arr[i] === "[") {
          arr[i] = "х";
        } else if (arr[i] === "{") {
          arr[i] = "Х";
        } else if (arr[i] === "]") {
          arr[i] = "ъ";
        } else if (arr[i] === "}") {
          arr[i] = "Ъ";
        } else if (arr[i] === "|") {
          arr[i] = "/";
        } else if (arr[i] === ";") {
          arr[i] = "ж";
        } else if (arr[i] === ":") {
          arr[i] = "Ж";
        } else if (arr[i] === "'") {
          arr[i] = "э";
        } else if (arr[i] === "\"") {
          arr[i] = "Э";
        } else if (arr[i] === ",") {
          arr[i] = "б";
        } else if (arr[i] === "<") {
          arr[i] = "Б";
        } else {
          arr[i] = arr[i];
        }
      }
      russian_text.value = arr.join('');


    }
  </script>
  <form onsubmit="transcript();">
    <input type="text" id="deutch_text" placeholder="Текст на немецком">
    <input type="text" id="russian_text" placeholder="Текст на русском" disabled>
    <input type="button" value="Транскрибировать" onclick="transcript();">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```